Get currently used url of an image-set (like .currentScr for images)
When you have an <img> with srcset attribute, you can use $0.currentSrc to get the source the browser chose from the srcset. The CSS equivalent of srcset is a background-image with image-set. But is there an equivalent to .currentSrc for those?

One super hacky way would be to look which resource gets fetched. The best would probably be to use a ServiceWorker for this, or you could try with performance.getEntriesByType("resource"), but once cached that may not appear there anymore... https://jsfiddle.net/7k0pbL58/
